# How to do summation of parameter values in ssrs

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008-r2

How to write the following in SSRS expression .
=(X/7+Y+Z)

I have tried something like this 
=iif (Fields!A_name.Value = "A",Fields!out.Value/7,0) + iif (Fields!A_name.Value= "B",Fields!out.Value,0)  + 
iif (Fields!A_name.Value = "c",Fields!out.Value,0)

With above expression  I am facing error.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

The expression you written is absolute correct, i checked it is working fine for me. Please share detail error that your are getting.

Thanks

Comment: It is giving result only for first IIF condition , what I am expecting is sum of all the three conditions.
sum of same parameter for different parameter values.